# SQL. Выборка из двух таблиц: если в первой пусто, то ищем во второй

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть две таблицы, с одинаковой структурой.
К примеру, `Table1: (id, value)` и такая же `Table2 (id, value)`.

Нужно выбирать данные из таблиц по `id` следующим образом:

сначала посмотреть в `Table1`: если там есть строка с таким `id`, то взять ее. Если нет, то посмотреть в таблицу `Table2` и взять оттуда.

Можно ли это сделать одним `SQL` запросом?

Comment: select coalesce (t1.value, t2.value) from t1, t2 where t1.id = 1 or t2.id = 1

Comment: Но ведь может быть, к примеру, в первой таблице у id=1 -  t1.value = null, тогда оно выберет из второй. А мне надо, чтобы из первой выбрало

Comment: @des1roer Ваше предложение выберет все записи как из T1 так и из T2, т.к. таблицы переклеятся и когда для T1.id=1, условие оказывается истинно для любых записей из T2 !!!

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN и DISTINCT(id) не подходит?

Comment: @Stack Не distinct(id) конечно, но full outer хорошая штука ...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

```
select decode(T1.id,NULL,T2.value,T1.value)
  from (select 341 as id from DUAL) A
  left join table1 T1 on T1.id=A.Id
  left join table2 T2 on T2.id=A.Id
```

Вот так, 341 - это искомый ID. То же самое в чисто орракловом стиле, как мне больше нравится, т.к. короче:

```
select decode(T1.id,NULL,T2.value,T1.value)
  from (select 341 as id from DUAL) A, table1 T1, table2 T2
 where T1.id(+)=A.Id and T2.id(+)=A.Id
```

Пояснение: когда в T1 запись не нашлась, то ее ID=NULL значит нам надо взять значение из T2, иначе из T1. Для других СУБД вместо `decode` можно применить `case when T1.id is null then T2.value else T1.value end`.

Если выборка нужна для многих записей, то что нибудь в этом роде (по подсказке Stack), только для версий Oracle >= 9i :

```
select nvl(T1.id,T2.id) as id, decode(T1.id,NULL,T2.value,T1.value) as value
  from table1 T1 full join table2 T2
    on T2.id=T1.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Если у Вас полностью одинаковые таблицы, может не стоит так делать, а разместить всё в одной- просто добавить там поле, которое чем-то отличает значения? а создавать табл 1,2,3,4...х с одинаковой структурой, потом ломать голову, как это обработать- как-то не вариант...
Создайте Table (id, value,table)  -ну table- это поле, почему вы разделили на таблицу 1 и 2

Comment: К сожалению, система не моя, и эти таблицы уже есть.

Comment: Если система не ваша - сделайте обзор на таблицы) Который их объединит с флагом и используйте, как сказал @Rakzin Roman

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH tmp AS
  (
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 13
  )

SELECT
 tmp.*
FROM tmp

UNION ALL

SELECT 
 table2.*
FROM
 (SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tmp)),
 table2
WHERE
 id = 13
```

Запрос получается более громоздкий чем предложил Mike. Но в данном случае может быть несколько плюсов, которые зависят от структуры таблиц.

1. Выборка по таблице Table2 не будет производиться, если в первой таблице не оказалось записей. Может пригодится в том случае если отсутствуют индексы по полю id.
2. В случае если id не уникально. При использовании джоинов таблиц мы получим перемножение данных (как пример в каждой таблице есть по две записи с искомым id, используя left или full мы на выходе получим 4 строчки). Данный же запрос не допустит такого перемножения.

   Во всех остальных случаях запросы предложенные Mike удобней и понятней для восприятия.

Answer (score -1):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
SELECT
    id
    ,value
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id
        ,value
        ,1 select_order
    FROM
        Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        id
        ,value
        ,2 select_order
    FROM
        Table1
) X
WHERE
    X.id = <id для поиска>
ORDER BY
    select_order
LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE**

Тут в комментариях подсказывают, что в `oracle` нет `limit` - поэтому нужно его заменить на аналог в `oracle`

Comment: я тоже так подумал. Но здесь будет выводить обе таблицы- пользователю вроде нужно сперва первую, и если нет- то вторую. Или нет?

Comment: И тут limit которого нет в oracle

Comment: @RakzinRoman, если будут данные в первой, то возьмет из первой иначе - из второй.

Comment: @Mike, с oracle не знаком, думал там limit есть

Comment: @Donil В оракле есть rownum, но проверять его надо в where. И следовательно весь ваш запрос заключить еще в один select и уже в его where проверить rownum<2. В общем довольно громоздко выходит